# NSMapTable releases entry before keys deallocates

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some confusion using `NSMapTable`.

I have `NSMapTable` with `NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory`:

```
    _controllersTable = [[NSMapTable alloc] initWithKeyOptions:NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory|NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality
                                                  valueOptions:NSPointerFunctionsWeakMemory|NSPointerFunctionsObjectPointerPersonality
                                                      capacity:0];
```

Assume I create `UIViewController` and add it to MapTable:

```
MyVC *myVC = [[MyVC alloc] init];
[self.controllersTable setObject:@1 forKey:controller]
```

**MyVC.m**

```
- (void)dealloc {

    // [[[controllersTable keyEnumerator] allObjects] count]] == 0

}
```

So, by the time MyVC calls dealloc, there is not entry for that VC. Are there any way to get value from `NSMapTable` in that case?

**PS**

I can't use `NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory` for storing keys, because it can introduce retain cycle.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the purpose of this map table? Are the values really numbers?? Unretained numbers???

Comment: "So, by the time MyVC calls dealloc, there is not entry for that VC" of course. That is exactly what a zeroing weak reference is!

Comment: @matt, yes, but it occurs BEFORE object finishes its deallocation process. The real values, I store in mapTable is other objects, but it's not related to question. My goal is to get this object before deallocating object, that is a key in maptable

Comment: Then you will have to do it before dealloc. I repeat, the whole point of zeroing weak references is that they are nilified before dealloc is called. How else could they work to prevent retain cycles??

Comment: Again I ask what you are really trying to do.